# Creating files go to which account using Google Drive APIs when authenticating with a service account?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make use of the Google Drive APIs to send a log file created by our application to our company's Google Drive Account that we share for Android Development.  Most of the examples showed how to use oAuth2 to authenticate with the end-user's Google Drive Account, but we want the files to be sent to just our Google Drive Account.

After some searching I found that I should create an API project for our app and use a Service account associated with that API Project to generate a key which we include in our project as a raw resource to authenticate using oAuth2 to get a GoogleCredential which is needed to build the Drive service we will use to make our API calls.

After authenticating properly, I was able to insert a file using the code example on the Google Drive API site and that appears to work properly, however I cannot see the file in our Google Drive account which created the API Project/Service account.  Despite this, if I call Drive.files().list().execute() and output the FileList to a string I was able to see the files our app has previously inserted into the Service account's Google Drive.

**So my question is:** Is there a new Google Drive account created for the Service account that is separate from the Google Drive account that created the Service account?  If so, is there a way to login to that account and view the files using the normal Google Drive Web UI so that we can get to the log files without writing some other application that authenticates with the Service account and then grabs the files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't see the files and folders created via code in my Google Drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211859/i-cant-see-the-files-and-folders-created-via-code-in-my-google-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears my question ended up being a duplicate, the other question one was just a little bit hard to find for me.  The question is [I can't see the files and folders created via code in my Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12211859/994519) and it was answered by a Google employee: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12218662/994519