# Visual interface Google Drive for app

Tags: google-drive-api

Maybe this is a silly question, but I've been trying to look information about it on internet without luck.

I have an app that uses Google Drive SDK. I was wondering if there is an option to actually access my files stored for my app like I can access my personal files in [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/%E2%80%8E)

I have a small mess with some folders and it will be easier if I can actually manage them with a visual interface.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to clarify or might get voted down. Show a code example.

Comment: @ZigMandel I'm using a application-owned account, as pinoyyid commented below (maybe that clarifies more my question). I don't think my code will add more info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your app uses a Service Account? If so, then there is no UI. See this question [I can't see the files and folders created via code in my Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211859/i-cant-see-the-files-and-folders-created-via-code-in-my-google-drive/12218662#12218662)

Comment: Pinoyyid you are right, I'm using a service account and I was trying to use the web UI. So I see I cannot do it with this kind of account. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Aha. You cant with a service account. However you could share the files and folders with a "real" account and see them. Easier to do if you already have everything inside a root folder so you only share that folder.

Comment: Hey Zig Mandel, this sounds very interesting. I'm going to read some information about how to achieve this. I will give a feedback.