# Cannot find files that I uploaded to google drive using google drive sdk

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using .NET SDK for google drive.
I have successfully managed to upload a file on google drive but when I log in using browser cannot see the file there?

Here is my code:

```
    private string privKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\MYKEYHERE-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

    private string[] scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
    string serviceAccountEmail = "<myaccounthere>";

    public File uploadToDrive(string uploadFilePath)
    {
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = scopes
        }.FromPrivateKey(privKey));

        BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        };

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(initializer);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadFilePath))
        {
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            fileMetadata.Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath);
            fileMetadata.MimeType = GetMimeType(uploadFilePath);

            try
            {
                System.IO.FileStream uploadStream = new System.IO.FileStream(uploadFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, uploadStream, GetMimeType(uploadFilePath));
                request.ProgressChanged += Upload_ProgressChanged;
                request.ResponseReceived += UploadRequest_ResponseReceived;

                var task = request.UploadAsync();
                task.ContinueWith(t =>
                {

                });
                return request.ResponseBody;


            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException iox)
            {
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                //Log
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Log file does not exist
            return null;
        }
    }

    private string GetMimeType(string fileName)
    {
        string mimeType = "application/unknown";

        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();

        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);

        if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
            mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();

        return mimeType;
    }

    private void Upload_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress progress)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(progress.Status + " " + progress.BytesSent);
    }

    private void UploadRequest_ResponseReceived(Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(file.Name + " was uploaded successfully");
    }
```

Does anyone happen to know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: as highlighted by abielita and pinoyyid below, your program is using a Service account. But, when you login using browser, you are using your usual account. Both accounts do not share own a different set of files & folder in Google Drive, unless you explicitly share specific files and folders between them.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, you can try the suggested answer in this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211859/i-cant-see-the-files-and-folders-created-via-code-in-my-google-drive):

> Since you are using a Service Account, all the folders and files will be created in this Service Account's Drive which cannot be accessed through a web UI and will be limited to the default quota.
>
> To add content in a user's Drive, you will need to go through the regular OAuth 2.0 flow to retrieve credentials from this user. You can find more information about OAuth 2.0 on this pages:
>
> - [Retrieve and use OAuth 2.0 credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials).
> - [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart): it has a quickstart sample in C# that you could use.
> - [Using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. Service accounts have this limitation. For anyone that has the same problem what I did (using .NET) to overcome this was to enable Domain-Wide delegation and impersonate the account that I needed.

e.g my service account is srv1@myaccount.gserviceaccount.com impersonates srv1@gmail.com

```
 ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("srv1@myaccount.gserviceaccount.com")
            {
                Scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                User = "srv1@gmail.com"
            }.FromPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY));
```

When I login to google drive using srv1@gmail.com I can now see the files