# Unable to access file created in drive through api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to create a new file in my drive and after successfully authenticating using service account id and client_key on rails I can see the id of the file being created but it seems the file is getting created in the drive for iam.gservice.com (the service account id) and I am unable to access it. Can someone please help me how do i access the file?

Comment: I have already given the permission for service account actor but that doesn't solve my problem either

Comment: Please share what you already have done like code used and also details of the encountered error. Are there errors that appear in the logs? Also, you may want to also try the suggested solution in this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211859/i-cant-see-the-files-and-folders-created-via-code-in-my-google-drive) and see if it helps.