# How do I retrieve details of files and folders created in google drive web interface via api?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

If I create a new folder in google drive web interface, the metadata is not retrieved via a call from api in c#.

However if I upload files or create folders via api, the metadata is returned as expected.

Problem is the opposite (almost) of this one, where the user cannot see files in the web interface uploaded via api...
[I can't see the files and folders created via code in my Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211859/i-cant-see-the-files-and-folders-created-via-code-in-my-google-drive)

All files are visible for me in the google drive web interface, but I only get details of those created via api in my code, below.

(edit) I should add, I've tried using every 'DriveService.Scope' available to me.

(edit2) I have observed that if I change ApplicationName, none of the previously uploaded files are retrieved either, but new uploads are.

```
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
listRequest.PageSize = 10;
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, size, mimeType)";

IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;
return files;
```

CTOR

```
public GoogleDrive(string appname)
    {
        ApplicationName = appname;
        error = new Error();

        try
        {
            credential = GetCredential();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex as Error;

        }

        try
        {
            // Create Drive API service.
            service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = this.ApplicationName,
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex as Error;
        }
    }
```

GetCredential method

```
private UserCredential GetCredential()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        try

        {
            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/gd-cred-" + ApplicationName + ".json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            }
            return credential;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex as Error;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you using Oauth2 or a service account?

Comment: I'm using Oauth2.

Comment: and you are authenticating your code with the same user as you are using to access the web interface?   your only requesting 10 files in that request have you also implemented pagination to get the next set of results?

Comment: It might help if you include your authentication code.   This sounds like a permissions issue.   Your code using the API does not appear to be the same user as the one you are using on the web applicaiton.

Comment: It is certainly the same user, I can see the files I upload via c# api, when I log into google and go to drive. I will add auth code when I get back shortly, it is straight from api reference.

Comment: Added code to OP.